# Why cannot I install dplyr from CRAN for R 3.2.3?

Tags: r, dplyr

I got an error message when trying to install `dplyr` package under R 3.2.3

```
> install.packages("dplyr")
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/src/contrib:
Line starting '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLI ...' is malformed!
Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)
```

Comment: I get the same error. I gave up waiting for the site admins to fix it and went to the repo at the Fred-Hutch (Seattle).

Comment: FWIW, I think that the fundamental problem is that the site is set up as http:// and is misclassified as https:// in the list of CRAN repos.

Comment: There is simply no reason not to default to `https://cran.rstudio.com` which is a) fast, b) on a cdn and hence 'network-close' to anybody and c) hosted professionally.

Comment: I just updated my R-version linux RHEL-6 to 3.2.3 and had the same problem. Trying the Rstudio cran repo gives the same error but changing to `http` rather than `https` solves it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also failed to install plyr from the repository `US (CA 1) [https]` with `R 3.2.3`. Below is the error message I got:

```
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.2:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.2/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)
```

By curiosity, I tried to install other packages from the same repository, eg `ggplot2`. All my attempts were vain.

Solution was to pick up another repository, eg `Spain (Madrid) https`.